# Can I safely mount a 150lb punching bag to the bottom chords of the trusses in my garage?

Tags: wood, framing, ceiling, garage, hanging

I’d mount a 2x4 or 2x6 on the other side of the drywall perpendicular across the chords pictured and hang the punching bag to that. These chords span about 50-60 feet.

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>
[image] [image]

If these chords aren’t suitable for supporting this type of load, my plan is to fasten 2x4s to the studs in the garage directly beneath and run several 2x4 “joists” across the garage supported by them. I know my terminology isn’t great, hopefully it still makes sense.

Thanks

Comment: In the first picture are we looking down, and seeing the back of the garage ceiling and some flooring attached to the truss?

Comment: @jay613 Yes, exactly. This Picture is taken from the garage attic looking down at the exact spot that I propose mounting a 2x4 or 2x6 perpendicular.

Comment: I'm not sure the truss is meant to support any of that.  All the weight of the ceiling and floor and I think you, are supported by a couple of nails in the vertical member.  Definitely don't add anything.

Comment: Damn. That makes sense. Hopefully the storage area up there is safe. I’ve been walking up there a decent bit.

Comment: It is the `150 pounds that moves that causes problems, swinging back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably fine, but I'd install a beam (or beams) across the bottom chords of several trusses and pack down from that to the back of the drywall and bolt through the packing into the beam.

Comment: Sorry, I understand installing a beam across several cords and then bolting the mounting hardware through both the cord and the new beam, but I do not understand what I’m supposed to pack? Thank you for the reply.

Comment: fill the gap between the drywall and the beam with wood in the location where you want to install the eye bolt to hold the punchbag.